# Snowpark calling pre-compiled Java UDFs

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am working on a very simple Snowflake example to call a pre-compiled Java UDF from Intellij. I have made a jar out of my Java UDF and want to call this from Intellij where i am trying to execute the UDF on snowflake.

I want to know how I can upload this jar into snowflake ?

```
    session.udf.registerTemporary("sampleJUdf", 
        "C:\\project_existing\\snowpark\\src\\main\\Java\\myjarfile.jar")
```

Comment: What's the actual issue?

Comment: oops missed that, I want to know how I can upload this jar into snowflake from Intellij ?

Comment: That is done automatically by Snowpark, you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Can you share more about the context? This should have been handled automatically, didn't it? What was the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the jar file using Session.addDependency() for example

```
session.addDependency("C:\\project_existing\\snowpark\\src\\main\\Java\\myjarfile.jar")
```

Then you need to refer the name of the function you have in your myjarfile.jar that is going to be used by the UDF, for example

```
session.udf.registerTemporary("sampleJUdf", myFunc)
```

If the jar is part of your running application SNowpark should automatically try to upload it, but you need to import it in your code and refer the name of the function in registerTemporary.

See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/creating-udfs.html#specifying-dependencies-for-a-udf for more details.

Comment: Hi Mats, thanks for your reply it was helpful, I can add the jar into snowflake stage. Can we create named udf or register permanent udf by giving a function name (I intend to create my function separately and needs to be 20-30 lines of code) ? This way I can expose udf for other users as well as a data service. if this is possible how to do it ?

Comment: Yes, by using session.udf.registerPermanent but then you need to have a stage defined as well, so for for examp if you have a stage called mystage in the database and schema you are adding the UDF to you do
session.udf.registerPermanent("sampleJUdf", myFunc, "mystage")